# Optimizing a bubble sort in C that will decrease the number of swaps needed to sort a list of numbers in ascending order

Tags: c, bubble-sort

To my understanding, the bubble sort (inefficient version) will do as follows:

```
2 3 8 6 23 14 16 1 123 90  (10 elements)
```

1. Compare element `[0]` and element `[1]`
2. If `[0]` is bigger than `[1]`, then a swap is completed.
3. If `[1]` is bigger than `[0]`, then no swap is complete.

Then the bubble sort will move onto comparing elements `[1]` and `[2]` and so forth, creating a total of 9 swaps.

However, could there be a way to guarantee that on the first pass, the highest number will be in its proper place at `[9]`, and that on a second pass, the two highest numbers will be in their proper places at `[7]` and `[8]`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There are other sorting algorithms (quicksort), and there is a theoretical result that sort has O(n log n ) complexity at least.

Comment: I've been looking at quicksort, and I don't think I quite understand what it actually does. Would you mind giving a basic explanation of what it does differently from bubble sort?

Comment: No, there are excellent books (in libraries) explaining that. Don't be shy reading books; they explain much better than a forum can.

Comment: @user994559 what exactly are you asking?

Comment: Bubble sort performs multiple passes over the array.  The Wikipedia articles on various sorting algorithms (quicksort, bubble sort, insertion sort, etc.) tend to be pretty good; they include animations of the algorithms at work.  (What you've described is only a single pass; bubble sort has to perform multiple passes.  The first time I read your question, I got the impression that you thought that one pass was the entire algorithm.)

Comment: The Wikipedia [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) page has a good description of the algorithm with pseudocode and two optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use bubble sort. Consider superior algorithms, such as

- [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)
- [Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
- [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) (which happens to be worse than two above in a pessimistic case)

Encountering a question *How do I optimise bubble sort* my answer is optimise it as long as it isn't Timsort yet.

Comment: Well, it seems like a valid answer to it ;)

Comment: I do like the answer, so +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Bubble sort is a specific algorithm -- it doesn't really make sense to ask if it can be optimized to have the property you want. It also has O(n^2) complexity, which is why it is rarely used.

There are other sorting algorithms, like selection sort, which will have a property closer to what you want. [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) will guarantee that on the i'th pass, the minimum i elements are in the correct positions. However, selection sort is also O(n^2), and should be avoided if you anticipate sorting a decent amount of data.

Like Basile and Jan, I recommend learning a more efficient and standard sorting algorithm, quicksort. Quicksort is very widely used, and is available in the C standard library. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)'s description of the algorithm is relatively concise; a search on Google will also give many animated versions of quicksort, which can be quite helpful for learning the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If you've implemented the bubble sort algorithm correctly, the highest number *must* always be in the right place at the end of the first pass.

The optimization is simply to go one step less at the end of the second pass:

```
let n equal top_element - 1
while n is greater than or equal to zero
  for i = 0 to n
    if element i is greater than element i+1 then swap
  subtract 1 from n
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things can be done to optimize bubble-sort. First, keep track if any swaps occurred during a single pass. If none occurred, then the list must have been completely sorted by that point, so you don't have to make any additional passes. Also, decrease the range of the loop each pass, as one more element should be in the correct position after each pass.